# Primes which remain prime when you reverse the digits

Tags: number-theory

Let $p$ be a "**special**" prime iff it gives another prime when the digits are reversed.

For example, $13$ is a special prime as $31$ is also prime.
More examples are $101,17,37\dots$ etc.

Are there infinitely many **special** primes?

Comment: Are you talking about palindrome primes?

Comment: not exactly....for example, $13$ is not a palindromic prime but it's a special prime...palindromic primes are numbers which are both prime and is a palindrome number.

Comment: it is a conjecture that palindromic primes are infinite...it doesn't prove our problem...please think before writing

Comment: Yes @ThomasAndrews I misread that

Comment: I think I heard someone say on this site that it is an open problem if there exist infinite number of primes of the form $10^k+1, k \in \mathbb Z$. All of those would be special and a very special case of special too.

Comment: Undoubtedly this is an open question. Tabulated at http://oeis.org/A007500

Comment: thanks........!

Comment: Notions about numbers in a specific base usually doesn't play along with concepts defined arithmetically (such as "primes").  That means that if there is an answer out there, the proof is probably ugly.

Comment: primes with the described property are also called emirp's. Palindromic primes have the desired property, so proving that infinite many palindromic primes exist would prove that infinite many emirp's exist unless you forbid that a special prime is palindromic.

Comment: Heuristically, it is almost certain that infinite many special non-palindromic primes exist. The statistical distribution of the primes clearly speaks for this assumption, but of course this is no proof.

Comment: In the first $10^5$ primes they are $17\%$, while In the first $10^6$ they are $16\%$ and in the first $10^7$ they are $15\%$. The 3 percentages are almost exact. Then I went on and discovered that there are no such numbers between $100$ millionth prime and $101$ millionth prime! There no such primes between the $1000000000$th and the $1000100000$th

Comment: There are no such numbers in $10$ millions after the billionth prime.

Comment: Palindromic primes are trivially special, so your question is open because so is for palindromic.

Comment: Wikipedia [states](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palindromic_prime): *It is not known if there are infinitely many palindromic primes in base 10*.